# Is “Children are easy to influence” correct sentence?

Tags: sentence-construction

I made the following sentences. I think it’s best to say “Children are easily influenced”. But I am not sure if I should use the active or passive voice in this construction.

> 1. Children are easy to influence.
> 2. Children are easy to influence with ads.
> 3. Children are easy to influence by ads.
> 4. These instructions are easy to follow by students.

Comment: Hi, welcome to ELL! Please keep in mind that asking us to pick the right one for you is considered a proofreading request and thus off topic here. In order to help prevent the closure of your question, I have edited your question slightly so it is more in-line with our question policy. Please always tell you what you think and why you think some sentences are grammatical/ungrammatical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Children are easily influenced* is a general comment, but your first three sentences imply the speaker's *intention* to influence children (in (2) and (3) the speaker would probably be someone in the advertising business).

(4) would be better expressed as *These instructions are easy for students to follow.*

Comment: Thanks. Do you think sentence 2 is more natural than sentence 3?

Comment: Yes, probably. _Easy to influence with_ but _easily influenced by_.